# Using nested mlogit function in R - having memory problems?

Tags: r

I am trying to model a decision tree in R using the `mlogit` function.  The aim of the model is to describe choices of boaters at the Channel Islands. The way we want to set up our model is with two decision tiers.  First, individuals select an activity (such as scuba, snorkeling, or kayaking).  Second, based on that activity, they select a site at the islands to visit based on that site’s attributes that are favorable for that activity (kelp cover, invertebrates, fish, etc).  We believe this is a nested structure, with first activity choice, then site choice.  The model has 4 different activities, and 31 different sites to choose from, for a total of 124 unique "activity-choice" options.  We have data from 111 individuals, who each made a particular decision, based on attributes at the various sites.

For the R code, we first describe our nests.  we next use the mlogit.data function to read in and prepare the data, and finally use the mlogit function to run the model.  However, after running the code, we get the following

```
error: "Error in model.matrix.default(formula, data: allocMatrix: too many elements specified".
```

Is this a RAM issue?  Is there a more efficient way to set up the problem?  Or are we going about this completely wrong?

Here is our code.

```
library(mlogit)
data.raw = read.csv("final_R_rum.csv",header=T)
underwater = c(1.1,2.1,3.1,4.1,5.1,6.1,7.1,8.1,9.1,10.1,11.1,12.1,13.1,14.1,15.1,16.1,17.1,18.1,19.1,20.1,21.1,22.1,23.1,24.1,25.1,26.1,27.1,28.1,29.1,30.1,31.1)
surface = c(1.2,2.2,3.2,4.2,5.2,6.2,7.2,8.2,9.2,10.2,11.2,12.2,13.2,14.2,15.2,16.2,17.2,18.2,19.2,20.2,21.2,22.2,23.2,24.2,25.2,26.2,27.2,28.2,29.2,30.2,31.2)
consumptive = c(1.3,2.3,3.3,4.3,5.3,6.3,7.3,8.3,9.3,10.3,11.3,12.3,13.3,14.3,15.3,16.3,17.3,18.3,19.3,20.3,21.3,22.3,23.3,24.3,25.3,26.3,27.3,28.3,29.3,30.3,31.3)
land = c(1.4,2.4,3.4,4.4,5.4,6.4,7.4,8.4,9.4,10.4,11.4,12.4,13.4,14.4,15.4,16.4,17.4,18.4,19.4,20.4,21.4,22.4,23.4,24.4,25.4,26.4,27.4,28.4,29.4,30.4,31.4)

data.logit = mlogit.data(data.raw,shape="long",choice="choice",alt.var="site_activity")
results=mlogit(formula=choice~fish_abun|total_TC_water_land,nests = list(underwater, surface, consumptive, land), data=data.logit)
summary(results)
```

Comment: Hard to tell without a reproducible example. what are the dimensions (`dim`) of the raw data and the data frame produced by `mlogit.data`?

Comment: The dimensions are 13764 x 28.  I understand it must be hard to fully comprehend the problem without seeing the data and trying it yourself, but unfortunately we can't release it at this time!

Comment: I'd call it a specification problem. You appear to be coding discrete data as decimal values when it would make more sense to code as factors. I suspect that the "nests" argument is specifying a 31^4 matrix.  I also have some doubts that data from 111 individuals will be adequate in supporting a nested analysis where there are a greater number of activity-choice possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for your comments DWin.  I made the nests into factors, but am still having the same issue.  As far as having more activity-choice possibilities than individuals, we've been worried as well that that could be a problem.  Is there maybe a way to bootstrap the data in order to tackle this problem?

Comment: I sorry that you thought I was suggesting that making those categories into factors would solve the problem that the nests specification were be the issue relating to the memory error. I don't think you should be specifying 31 levels in each of the nest components.